# Связка Objective-C++ и Swift

Tags: c++, видео, swift, gif

Добрый день!

Возможно, у кого-то есть опыт в связывании Swift и C++. Мне нужно сделать примерно следующее:

1. У меня есть написанный класс на Swift, который анализирует видео и находит индексы фреймов, которые совпадают.
2. Следующим пунктом я бы хотел извлечь кусок видео и сделать зацикленную gif-ку (и, к сожалению, я не нашел способа, чтобы сделать это на Swift для OS X).
3. Я нашел библиотеку на C++ (Magick++), и решил связать Swift с C++.

Возникает логичные вопросы:

1. Как согласовать разные типы в разных языках (в C++ это Magick::Image, а в Swift - CImageRef)

Если избегать согласования разных типов (после анализа я могу передать номера фреймов, которые совпали, т.е. пары), передавать это в C++ (кстати, я могу передавать пары из Swift в C++?), тогда как в C++

1. Работать с видео (вырезать часть видео, обращаться к кадрам видео)
2. Работать с GIF (формировать из видеозаписи, сохранять в файл) - это почти понятно, то вот связать с видеозаписью у меня не получается, расскажите, есть ли какой способ?

Спасибо большое заранее.

PS: правильно было бы говорить "Objective-C++" вместо "C++", но, я думаю, вы меня поняли.

PPS: есть еще пару вариантов:

1. Objective-C поддерживает библиотеки C (если я не ошибаюсь), попробовать libgd
2. Или же (я точно не знаю), есть способ решить это на Objective-C, но я совсем в нем не разбираюсь

Помогите советом.

Comment: Вы написали кучу текста и не привели ни одной строчки кода с конкретными проблемами. Если у вас несколько проблем, то следует запостить отдельные вопросы, в которых каждая проблема полноценно раскрывается: что вы сделали, что не работает и т.п. У вас же какая-то мешанина из описаний, вопросов и посткриптумов, гвоздями прибитая к вашей конкретной программе.

Comment: Я описал, что у меня есть. И спросил, как связать обработку видео с формированием gif-ки. Реально ли это? А дальше спросил, какими из способов это можно сделать (и привел различные варианты, которые, возможно, нереально осуществить). И мне интересно услышать мнение, так как у меня нет соответствующего опыта.
Вкратце, мне нужно узнать, есть ли такие библиотеки, которые, работая вместе, смогли бы мне обеспечить обработку видео + формирование GIF из кусков этого видео.

Comment: Скорее всего, здесь лучше использовать Objective-C. Я большой сторонник Swift, но там, где нужно использовать код на C или C++ - использую Objective-C.